# Detectar evento de cambio de cámara por el usuario en Google Maps Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Con `onCameraMove` y `onCameraIdle` se intercepta al cambio de cámara en Google Maps.
Lo que quiero es detectar y diferenciar quien produce el cambio de cámara, si es de forma automática usando por ejemplo `mMap.moveCamera()` etc... o bien es el usuario que fuerza el cambio, arrastrando el mapa

Se puede detectar quien ha efectuado un cambio de cámara en Google Maps?

Comment: Creo que google ha añadido un evento más que me puede servir onCameraMoveStarted https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events#camera-change-events

Comment: Personalmente uso OnCameraIdleListener  ya que determino que termino el movimiento de camara, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisamente el listener es [setOnCameraMoveStartedListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events?hl=es-419) :

```
map.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onCameraMoveStarted(int i) {
                Log.i("Cam", "onCameraMoveStarted()");
            }
        });
```

También puedes usar `OnCameraIdleListener` para determinar cuando dejo de moverse la camara!, al terminar puedes realizar alguna función.

```
    map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraIdle() {
            Log.i("Cam", "onCameraIdle()");

        }
    });
```

> [GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener) : Llamado cuando el movimiento de la
>   cámara ha finalizado, no hay animaciones pendientes y el usuario ha
>   dejado de interactuar con el mapa.

Revisa [Eventos Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 0):

Mirando la documentación oficial de [Eventos Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events#camera-change-events) y complementando la solución del compañero @Jorsesys, con el evento `onCameraMoveStarted` se puede obtener quien ha empezado el movimiento de cámara, el valor de las razones:

- **REASON_GESTURE**: Cuando el usuario mueve el punto de cámara
- **REASON_API_ANIMATION**: Cuando el usuario hace un toque en el mapa
- **REASON_DEVELOPER_ANIMATION**: Cuando el punto de vista de la cámara se mueve automáticamente

Código de ejemplo

```
@Override
public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {

    if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onCameraMoveStarted: The user gestured on the map.");

    } else if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_API_ANIMATION) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onCameraMoveStarted: The user tapped something on the map.");

    } else if (reason == GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_DEVELOPER_ANIMATION) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onCameraMoveStarted: The app moved the camera.");

    }
}
```